# How to provide a CorDapp with custom config in Corda?

Tags: corda

I need to communicate with external system inside Corda flow so there should be a way to deliver some configuration (e.g. username and password for external API). It may be .properties or .yaml file for example.

Is there a best practice how to do that? Maybe even sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corda 3 doesn't have built-in support for providing arbitrary configuration files to nodes. Support for this will be added in Corda 4 using CorDapp configuration files: https://docs.corda.net/head/cordapp-build-systems.html#cordapp-configuration-files.

In the meantime, you can place a local file within the node directory and read from it directly within a flow. For example, if I place a configuration file called `properties.txt` in the node's root directory, I can then read back its contents using the following flow:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class ReadPropertiesFlow : FlowLogic<String>() {
    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() = File("./properties.txt").readText()
}
```

The node's working directory is always the node's root directory (except for when using the `MockNetwork` for flow tests).

Alternatively, you could store information directly in the node's database. See [NODE_PROPERTIES table in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491433/node-properties-table-in-database) for an example.