# Reading data from ENV variables in a subflow

Tags: corda

I am trying to make an API call from a sub-flow which is annotated with @InitiatedBy. Is there any way to read the API URL from an ENV variable in a sub-flow, instead of hard-coding it?
For example:

```
 @InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Acceptor(val otherPartyFlow: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]
        val txID = otherPartyFlow.receive<SecureHash>().unwrap { secureHash -> secureHash }
        val commitedId = waitForLedgerCommit(txID)
        val op = commitedId.tx.outputStates.single() as RequestState
        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)

        try {
            val res = khttp.get("http://localhost:3000/getTitle", timeout = 30.0).jsonObject.getString("data")
            val iouState = IOUState(res, serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first(), otherPartyFlow.counterparty)
            val txCommand = Command(RequestContract.Commands.Approve(), ourIdentity.owningKey)
            val txCommand1 = Command(IOUContract.Commands.Create(), ourIdentity.owningKey)
            txBuilder.addInputState(commitedId.tx.outRefsOfType<RequestState>().single())
            txBuilder.addOutputState(iouState, IOU_CONTRACT_ID)
            txBuilder.addOutputState(op.copy(status = "Transferred"), RequestContract.REQUEST_ID)
            txBuilder.addCommand(txCommand)
            txBuilder.addCommand(txCommand1)
            // Verify that the transaction is valid.
            txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)
            // Stage 3.
            val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)
            return subFlow(FinalityFlow(partSignedTx))
        }catch (ex: Exception){
            logger.info(ex.message)
            txBuilder.addInputState(commitedId.tx.outRefsOfType<RequestState>().single())
            val txCommand1 = Command(RequestContract.Commands.Expire(), ourIdentity.owningKey)
            txBuilder.addCommand(txCommand1)
            txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)
            // Stage 3.
            val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)
            return subFlow(FinalityFlow(partSignedTx))
        }
    }
}
```

The node on which the Acceptor flow is executed needs to retrieve some data from its external system over API. Currently it is hardcoded in the sub-flow code. Is it possible for a sub-flow to read the URL (http://localhost:3000/getTitle) from ENV variable / node.conf file?

Comment: You need to add a lot more context to that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Corda 4+**

Corda 4 will introduce the concept of CorDapp configuration files that will allow you to provide CorDapp-specific configuration.

These configuration files must be placed in the `<node_dir>/cordapps/config` folder. These files are loaded when a `CordappContext` is created and so can change during runtime.

The name of the file should match the name of the CorDapp JAR (e.g. if your CorDapp is called `hello-0.1.jar` the config file should be called `config/hello-0.1.conf`). The config files must be written in the Typesafe/Lightbend config format.

CorDapp configuration can be accessed from `CordappContext::config` whenever a `CordappContext` is available.

**Corda 3 alternatives**

In the meantime, in Corda 3, your best options are either to create your own local configuration files (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500297/how-to-provide-a-cordapp-with-custom-config-in-corda)), or to store the configuration in your node database (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491433/node-properties-table-in-database)).

Comment: Thanks Joel. local configuration files approach sounds good to me for now since i am using Corda3.2. how can I test it using MockNetwork flow tests?

Comment: I'm not sure. I *think* you might be able to parameterise the flow to take the path to the local file, and pass a different value in for the tests.

Comment: cool, thanks. joel, is there a way to add a new config file in the node directory using deployNodes task?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. You'd have to write your own additional Gradle task or script.