# How to get config file for Cordapp?

Tags: corda

How to get config file for Cordapp in Java like in sample?

```
serviceHub.getAppContext().config
```

After `getAppContext()` i can't find anything about config file.

Comment: Where have you seen this being used?

Comment: @Joel In samples: [link](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/samples/cordapp-configuration/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/configsample/GetStringConfigFlow.kt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available in Corda 3. As of this answer, it is only part of the unstable `master` branch. It will be included in a future release of Corda.

However, you can implement this manually for now as follows: [How to provide a CorDapp with custom config in Corda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500297/how-to-provide-a-cordapp-with-custom-config-in-corda).