# Node specific state variable in Corda?

Tags: corda

I have one question on Corda, how to add node specific state variable and how to initialize them dynamically. For example I want to set different Initial amount to each node while these are created, and then perform some actions on it based on flow. Is there anything that I can use as a reference.

TIA, Lalit

Answer (score 0):

In Corda 4, this will be possible using CorDapp configuration files: https://docs.corda.net/head/cordapp-build-systems.html#cordapp-configuration-files.

For the various workarounds possible in Corda 3, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48507043/4620025.